# javascript array with keys containing another array of objects using php

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an e-commerce project. the user can select multiple colors and can enter the quantity for each size of that color differently. I want to store that data into an array and then send it to the server using ajax

the array should look like this

```
[ {
   'color' : [ {
        'INDIGO' : [
                     { 'S' : 15},
                     { 'M' : 15},
        ] },{
        'PURPLE' : [
                     { 'S' : 15},
                     { 'M' : 15},
        ]},

   ]}
]
```

but I am getting this type of array. it is inserting the last quantity I have inserted replaces the old one like if on purple color if I put 15 for s and 15 for m it only takes m

INDIGO: {L: 15}
PURPLE: {M: 15}

here is my code sample

when the user selects color radio it pushes the value into the color array

```
var key = 'INDIGO';
color[key] = {};
```

and when the user increases quantity it inserts the object for the color key

```
var len = $('.radioCheckbox:checked');

for (var i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
    var key = len[i].value;
    color[key] = {
        [$size] : val,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like when you are putting the 15 for s and 15 for m  you color is not rightly set for each size. So check when you are pushing m or s the color is set correctly. Alternately, Not sure why do you need complex data structure. I think it can be achievable using data structure which is easy handle like

```
data = {
  'color': {
    'INDIGO': {
      'S': 15,
      'M': 15
    },
    'PURPLE': {
      'S': 15,
      'M': 15
    }
  }
}
```

you can manage color, size and its values like,

```
data['color'][key][$size] = val
```